# How do I fix these gaps between each list item?

Tags: html, css

I am creating a portfolio for myself and I am struggling with these list items. I want them to be the same height and inline with each other. In each list item there is one extra line and I believe that is what is causing it. How would I fix this?

Here is what it looks like:
[Picture of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DeQME.png)

```css
#content-wrapper {
  background-color: #EBEBEB;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 2.5px solid #0F0F0F;
}
#content-wrapper ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
#content-wrapper ul li {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  color: #1B1B1B;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px 2.5px;
  width: 45%;
}
#content-wrapper ul li p {
  padding: 10px;
  height: 150px;
}
#content-wrapper ul li img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="content-wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <img src="http://ashleye.co.uk/img/portfolio-1.png">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://ashleye.co.uk/img/portfolio-1.png">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed leo ligula, placerat at interdum vitae, maximus id leo.</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://ashleye.co.uk/img/portfolio-1.png">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed leo ligula, placerat at interdum vitae, maximus id leo. Donec pellentesque, leo sed aliquet vulputate, orci dui commodo tellus, et tempus nunc nulla quis diam.</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://ashleye.co.uk/img/portfolio-1.png">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed leo ligula, placerat at interdum vitae, maximus id leo. Donec pellentesque, leo sed aliquet vulputate, orci dui commodo tellus, et tempus nunc nulla quis diam. Vivamus diam neque, pellentesque
        at euismod et, tincidunt vitae eros.</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://ashleye.co.uk/img/portfolio-1.png">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed leo ligula, placerat at interdum vitae, maximus id leo. Donec pellentesque, leo sed aliquet vulputate, orci dui commodo tellus, et tempus nunc nulla quis diam. Vivamus diam neque, pellentesque
        at euismod et, tincidunt vitae eros. Vivamus mi justo, volutpat ut nisl sed, dictum pellentesque odio.</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://ashleye.co.uk/img/portfolio-1.png">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed leo ligula, placerat at interdum vitae, maximus id leo. Donec pellentesque, leo sed aliquet vulputate, orci dui commodo tellus, et tempus nunc nulla quis diam. Vivamus diam neque, pellentesque
        at euismod et, tincidunt vitae eros. Vivamus mi justo, volutpat ut nisl sed, dictum pellentesque odio. Nunc metus quam, rutrum sed metus convallis, egestas sodales quam.</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is another version of your code for you. everything is in line here.

any other questions, just ask :)

```
  <div class="project">
     <img src="http://ashleye.co.uk/img/portfolio-1.png">
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="project">
     <img src="http://ashleye.co.uk/img/portfolio-1.png">
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="project">
     <img src="http://ashleye.co.uk/img/portfolio-1.png">
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="project">
     <img src="http://ashleye.co.uk/img/portfolio-1.png">
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  </div>
```

```
body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
#wrapper{
  width:100%;
  height:2000px;
  background:#eee;
}
#portfolio{
  width:900px;
  height:1200px;
  margin:auto;
}
.project{
  width:47.5%;
  height:400px;
  background:#fff;
  float:left;
  margin:10px 2.5% 0 0;
}
.project img{
  width:80%;
  height:auto;
  margin-left:10%;
}
.project p{
  text-align:center;
}
```

http://codepen.io/raze444/pen/mOBjOx?editors=1100

Comment: Thank you! This helps, maybe I should of did this first time! I'm just learning the responsive design so this does help. Thanks again!

Comment: `height: 2000px`, `height:1200px;` will never help you on responsive design. :)

Comment: The point was not to make a responsive design lonut it was to show how to make the those in line, also when you are developing a website its a good idea to use a  placeholder height for the wrapper and then change it to auto when you are finished :)

Comment: I hardly disagree on the height part you just said. It's never a good way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Use `float: left;` instead of `display: inline-block;`, and should look fine. Also if you want to completely remove the spaces between them set `margin: 0;`, everything on `#content-wrapper ul li`:

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#content-wrapper {
  background-color: #EBEBEB;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}
#content-wrapper ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
#content-wrapper ul li {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  color: #1B1B1B;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
#content-wrapper ul li p {
  padding: 10px;
  height: 150px;
}
#content-wrapper ul li img {
  width: 100%;
}

#inner-wrapper{
  max-width: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-top: 2.5px solid #0F0F0F;
}
```

```html
<div id="content-wrapper">
  <div id='inner-wrapper'>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <img src="http://ashleye.co.uk/img/portfolio-1.png">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://ashleye.co.uk/img/portfolio-1.png">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed leo ligula, placerat at interdum vitae, maximus id leo.</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://ashleye.co.uk/img/portfolio-1.png">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed leo ligula, placerat at interdum vitae, maximus id leo. Donec pellentesque, leo sed aliquet vulputate, orci dui commodo tellus, et tempus nunc nulla quis diam.</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://ashleye.co.uk/img/portfolio-1.png">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed leo ligula, placerat at interdum vitae, maximus id leo. Donec pellentesque, leo sed aliquet vulputate, orci dui commodo tellus, et tempus nunc nulla quis diam. Vivamus diam neque, pellentesque
        at euismod et, tincidunt vitae eros.</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://ashleye.co.uk/img/portfolio-1.png">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed leo ligula, placerat at interdum vitae, maximus id leo. Donec pellentesque, leo sed aliquet vulputate, orci dui commodo tellus, et tempus nunc nulla quis diam. Vivamus diam neque, pellentesque
        at euismod et, tincidunt vitae eros. Vivamus mi justo, volutpat ut nisl sed, dictum pellentesque odio.</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://ashleye.co.uk/img/portfolio-1.png">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed leo ligula, placerat at interdum vitae, maximus id leo. Donec pellentesque, leo sed aliquet vulputate, orci dui commodo tellus, et tempus nunc nulla quis diam. Vivamus diam neque, pellentesque
        at euismod et, tincidunt vitae eros. Vivamus mi justo, volutpat ut nisl sed, dictum pellentesque odio. Nunc metus quam, rutrum sed metus convallis, egestas sodales quam.</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay so this does fix what I am trying to do however I can't seem to center it because it is floated. I tried to resize the wrapper and then margin:0 auto; that but then I lose the background color. Would I have to use a wrapper for the wrapper If that makes sense?

Comment: Add `max-width: 1000px;` let's say, to your container. Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

replace inline-block with inline-table on  #content-wrapper ul li for instant solution [LiveOnFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h79L63ve/1/) . On small screen  the last li p element overflow coz of the  p tag height 150px. So you can change it 200px or write media query for small screen.

```css
#content-wrapper {
  background-color: #EBEBEB;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 2.5px solid #0F0F0F;
}
#content-wrapper ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
#content-wrapper ul li {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  color: #1B1B1B;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-table;/*Change  inline-block to inline-table*/
  margin: 5px 2.5px;
  width: 45%;
}
#content-wrapper ul li p {
  padding: 10px;
  height: 200px; /*Change the height 150px to 200px*/
}
#content-wrapper ul li img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="content-wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <img src="http://ashleye.co.uk/img/portfolio-1.png">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://ashleye.co.uk/img/portfolio-1.png">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed leo ligula, placerat at interdum vitae, maximus id leo.</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://ashleye.co.uk/img/portfolio-1.png">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed leo ligula, placerat at interdum vitae, maximus id leo. Donec pellentesque, leo sed aliquet vulputate, orci dui commodo tellus, et tempus nunc nulla quis diam.</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://ashleye.co.uk/img/portfolio-1.png">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed leo ligula, placerat at interdum vitae, maximus id leo. Donec pellentesque, leo sed aliquet vulputate, orci dui commodo tellus, et tempus nunc nulla quis diam. Vivamus diam neque, pellentesque
        at euismod et, tincidunt vitae eros.</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://ashleye.co.uk/img/portfolio-1.png">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed leo ligula, placerat at interdum vitae, maximus id leo. Donec pellentesque, leo sed aliquet vulputate, orci dui commodo tellus, et tempus nunc nulla quis diam. Vivamus diam neque, pellentesque
        at euismod et, tincidunt vitae eros. Vivamus mi justo, volutpat ut nisl sed, dictum pellentesque odio.</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://ashleye.co.uk/img/portfolio-1.png">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed leo ligula, placerat at interdum vitae, maximus id leo. Donec pellentesque, leo sed aliquet vulputate, orci dui commodo tellus, et tempus nunc nulla quis diam. Vivamus diam neque, pellentesque
        at euismod et, tincidunt vitae eros. Vivamus mi justo, volutpat ut nisl sed, dictum pellentesque odio. Nunc metus quam, rutrum sed metus convallis, egestas sodales quam.</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you should use `flexbox` in place of `display-inline` something like below :

Add `display: flex` to parent container

```
 #content-wrapper ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;  
}
```

```css
#content-wrapper {
  background-color: #EBEBEB;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 2.5px solid #0F0F0F;
}
#content-wrapper ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;  
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;  
}
#content-wrapper ul li {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  color: #1B1B1B;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px 2px;
  width: 45%;
}
#content-wrapper ul li p {
  padding: 10px;
  height: 150px;
}
#content-wrapper ul li img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="content-wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <img src="http://ashleye.co.uk/img/portfolio-1.png">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://ashleye.co.uk/img/portfolio-1.png">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed leo ligula, placerat at interdum vitae, maximus id leo.</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://ashleye.co.uk/img/portfolio-1.png">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed leo ligula, placerat at interdum vitae, maximus id leo. Donec pellentesque, leo sed aliquet vulputate, orci dui commodo tellus, et tempus nunc nulla quis diam.</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://ashleye.co.uk/img/portfolio-1.png">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed leo ligula, placerat at interdum vitae, maximus id leo. Donec pellentesque, leo sed aliquet vulputate, orci dui commodo tellus, et tempus nunc nulla quis diam. Vivamus diam neque, pellentesque
        at euismod et, tincidunt vitae eros.</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://ashleye.co.uk/img/portfolio-1.png">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed leo ligula, placerat at interdum vitae, maximus id leo. Donec pellentesque, leo sed aliquet vulputate, orci dui commodo tellus, et tempus nunc nulla quis diam. Vivamus diam neque, pellentesque
        at euismod et, tincidunt vitae eros. Vivamus mi justo, volutpat ut nisl sed, dictum pellentesque odio.</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://ashleye.co.uk/img/portfolio-1.png">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed leo ligula, placerat at interdum vitae, maximus id leo. Donec pellentesque, leo sed aliquet vulputate, orci dui commodo tellus, et tempus nunc nulla quis diam. Vivamus diam neque, pellentesque
        at euismod et, tincidunt vitae eros. Vivamus mi justo, volutpat ut nisl sed, dictum pellentesque odio. Nunc metus quam, rutrum sed metus convallis, egestas sodales quam.</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

For documentation - [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)